# What guidelines and/or tools exist that facilitate the analysis of a program in assembly language for PIC-Microchip?

Tags: assembly, c, pic

What tools exist that facilitate the interpretation of a program written in assembly language of a PIC-Microchip, appealing to the construction, for example, of a flowchart and then recoding it in another language such as C (for a PIC or Arduino).I am analyzing the hardware of Phil Rice's tester (https://sites.google.com/site/vk3bhr/home/lcm1) with the Ltspice simulator to understand how the oscillator works and I was able to test the circuit on a breadboard. Now I would like to take another step with the program to understand it and thus propose improvements.